# Spark read parquet with custom schema

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to import data with parquet format with custom schema but it returns :
TypeError: option() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

```
   ProductCustomSchema = StructType([
        StructField("id_sku", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("flag_piece", StringType(), True),
        StructField("flag_weight", StringType(), True),
        StructField("ds_sku", StringType(), True),
        StructField("qty_pack", FloatType(), True)])

def read_parquet_(path, schema) : 
    return spark.read.format("parquet")\
                             .option(schema)\
                             .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")\
                             .load(path)

product_nomenclature = 'C:/Users/alexa/Downloads/product_nomenc'
product_nom = read_parquet_(product_nomenclature, ProductCustomSchema)
```

Comment: Not sure if it would work, but instead of `.option(schema)`, try `.schema(schema)`.

Comment: return Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1259.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 50.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 50.0 (TID 660, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Parquet column cannot be converted in file file:///C:/Users/alexa/Downloads/product_nomenc/lu_product_nomenclature%252Fpart-r-00002-8c115acd-057f-43a5-b7dd-0e7d0ef1eb9e.gz.parquet. Column: [id_sku], Expected: IntegerType, Found: BINARY

Comment: See valid signatures at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader (and out of interest why not spark.read.parquet() and infer the schema?)

Comment: for me adding `("recursive",true)`  as mentioned in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74188877/6490744 worked

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the comments you should change `.option(schema)` to `.schema(schema)`.  `option()` requires you to specify a `key` (the name of the option you're setting) and a `value` (what value you want to assign to that option).  You are getting the `TypeError` because you were just passing a variable called `schema` to `option` without specifying what that option you were actually trying to set with that variable.

The `QueryExecutionException` you posted in the comments is being raised because the schema you've defined in your `schema` variable does not match the data in your DataFrame.  If you're going to specify a custom schema you must make sure that schema matches the data you are reading.  In your example the column `id_sku` is stored as a `BinaryType`, but in your schema you're defining the column as an `IntegerType`.  `pyspark` will not try to reconcile differences between the schema you provide and what the actual types are in the data and an exception will be thrown.

To fix your error make sure the schema you're defining correctly represents your data as it is stored in the parquet file (i.e. change the datatype of `id_sku` in your schema to be `BinaryType`).  The benefit to doing this is you get a slight performance gain by not having to infer the file schema each time the parquet file is read.

Answer (score 0):

Use .option(schema=ProductCustomSchema)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).