# Write parquet from another parquet with a new schema using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, schema, parquet

I am using pyspark dataframes, I want to read a parquet file and write it with a different schema from the original file

The original schema is (It have 9.000 variables, I am just putting the first 5 for the example):

```
[('id', 'string'),
 ('date', 'string'),
 ('option', 'string'),
 ('cel1', 'string'),
 ('cel2', 'string')]
```

And I want to write:

```
[('id', 'integer'),
 ('date', 'integer'),
 ('option', 'integer'),
 ('cel1', 'integer'),
 ('cel2', 'integer')]
```

My code is:

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet("PATH")

### SOME OPERATIONS ###

write_schema = StructType([StructField('id'  , IntegerType(), True),
                           StructField('date'  , IntegerType(), True),
                           StructField('option'  , IntegerType(), True),
                           StructField('cel1'  , IntegerType(), True),
                           StructField('cel2'  , IntegerType(), True) ])


df.option("schema",write_schema).write("PATH")
```

After I run it I still have the same schema from the original data, everything is string, the schema did not changed

---

Also I tried using

```
df = sqlContext.read.option("schema",write_schema).parquet(PATH)
```

This option does not change the schema when I read it, It shows the original one, so I use (suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387021/spark-read-parquet-with-custom-schema)):

```
df = sqlContext.read.schema(write_schema).parquet(PATH)
```

These one works for the reading part, if I see the types I get:

```
df.dtypes

#>>[('id', 'int'),
#   ('date', 'int'),
#   ('option', 'int'),
#   ('cel1', 'int'),
#   ('cel2', 'int')]
```

But when I tried to write the parquet I get an error:

```
Parquet column cannot be converted. Column: [id], Expected: IntegerType, Found: BINARY
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your columns to `int` and then try writing to another parquet file. No schema specification needed.

```
df = spark.read.parquet("filepath")
df2 = df.select(*map(lambda col: df[col].cast('int'), df.columns))
df2.write.parquet("filepath")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, with 10MM rows and 9.000 columns, is this optimum? Does it parallelize?

Comment: It certainly does

Comment: Thanks, I will try it, just curious now, do you know why does the write.parquet does not change the schema?

Comment: @Joe that's because write.parquet does not accept schema as an argument - see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet

Answer (score 0):

for this you can actually enforce the schema right when reading the data.
you can modify the code as follows:

```
df = sqlContext.read.option("schema",write_schema).parquet("PATH")
df.write.parquet("NEW_PATH")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried it but it did not work, you can I updated the post

Comment: This isn't correct, parquet file contains the schema definition, you  can't just randomly read colunms a, b, c of types str from a file whose schema is columns x, y, z of types int.