# pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

***This has a different answer to those given in the post above***

I am getting an error that reads

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;'
```

when I try to read in a parquet file like such using Spark 2.1.0

```
data = spark.read.parquet('/myhdfs/location/')
```

I have checked and the file/table is not empty by looking at the impala table through the Hue WebPortal. Also, other files that I have stored in similar directories read absolutely fine. For the record, the file names contain hyphens but no underscores or full-stops/periods.

Hence, none of the answers in the following post apply  [Unable to infer schema when loading Parquet file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954892/unable-to-infer-schema-when-loading-parquet-file)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the answers on this post first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954892/unable-to-infer-schema-when-loading-parquet-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to infer schema when loading Parquet file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954892/unable-to-infer-schema-when-loading-parquet-file)

Comment: Yeap. I’ve read that and none of the answers apply.

Comment: Try reading an individual Parquet file by providing its full path and report the outcome.

Comment: Ah hah! It turns out there was another level in the directory structure!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out I was getting this error because there was another level to the directory structure. The following was what I needed;

```
data = spark.read.parquet('/myhdfs/location/anotherlevel/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem but none of the answers I found online worked for me. It turns out that I was writing the code in this way:

```
data = spark.read.parquet("/myhdfs/location/anotherlevel/")
```

so, using double " . When I switched to using single ' , my problem was solved.

```
data = spark.read.parquet('/myhdfs/location/anotherlevel/')
```

Sharing in case it helps anybody

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31376866)