# How to Ignore Empty Parquet Files in Databricks When Creating Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, databricks

I am having issues loading multiple files into a dataframe in Databricks.  When I load a parquet file in an individual folder, it is fine, but the following error returns when I try to load multiple files in the dataframe:

```
DF = spark.read.parquet('S3 path/')
```

> "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually."

Per other StackOverflow answers, I added `spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles` true to the cluster configuration but it didn't seem to resolve the issue.  Any other ideas?

Comment: have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954892/unable-to-infer-schema-when-loading-parquet-file.

Comment: As Venus is suggesting, stop writing empty files to avoid issues while reading.